# Will it be possible to generate several top-level classes with one macro invocation in scala 2.10?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

I have an program with lots of boilerplate (which is, sadly, not reducible even by Scala mechanisms). But if there would be a way to generate complex top-level classes with a macro, all that boilerplate will go away. For example:

```
package org.smth

generate(params)

// becomes

class A { ... }
object B { ... }
case class C { ... }
```

Will it be possible with Scala 2.10 macros?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: no.

[Macro types](http://ScalaMacros.Org/future.html) (i.e. macros that generate types instead of methods) are planned, but they are not designed nor specified, let alone implemented yet, and they won't be for 2.10.

Also, a single macro invocation can only generate a single type. However, since types (specifically, `object`s) can be nested, this is not a limitation: you can just generate a single top-level `object` containing all the classes you need. The difference between this and your code is basically one additional `import` statement:

```
package org.smth

type O = Generate(params)

// becomes

object O {
  class A { ... }
  object B { ... }
  case class C { ... }
}

// which means you need an additional

import O._
```

They thought about `package` macros that can generate entire packages full of classes, but realized that since `object`s are a superset of `package`s and type macros can generate `object`s that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: But is it possible to generate inner classes in method macros now? Like `val a = { class A { ... }; new A smth }`?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but local classes don't need to be registered in a global symbol table, so it's simple.

Comment: what is the return type of Generate(params)?